# How to create a flow?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I just started learning akka stream and would like to create a flow. 
I would say, I do understand the concept of flow but fail, when I try to use it.

From my example:

```
  final class Foo(value: String)

  def chain2: Flow[String, Foo, Future[Foo]] =
    Flow.
```

I do not know, how to finish it. The inlet is `String` and the outlet is `Foo`.

How to code it?

Comment: What have you already tried by yourself?

Comment: That what you see above.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this just

```
def chain2: Flow[String, Foo, NotUsed] = Flow.fromFunction[String, Foo](new Foo(_))
```

?

If you need to modify materilaized value you can use `mapMaterializedValue`

```
chain2.mapMaterializedValue(_ => Future(new Foo("abc"))): Flow[String, Foo, Future[Foo]]
```

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.22/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html